# How to access services exposed via ClusterIP when using Docker For Windows:

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I installed Docker for windows and the built in k8s single node cluster for dev purposes on a local workstation (windows 10 pro).

I'd like to know how to access services hosted on this cluster. It's not documented very well

I don't have a load balancer installed and don't need a K8s Ingress. How can I access a service hosted at 10.105.245.65:80 . localhost and 127.0.0.1 don't work and 10.105.245.65 has no meaning on the host windows machine .

I could use NodePort (that works) but I'd like to understand how to access via ClusterIP .

```
C:\Users\balamuvi>kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   52m
webserver    ClusterIP   10.105.245.65   <none>        80/TCP    48m ===> how do I access this service

C:\Users\balamuvi>kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443 =======> resolves to localhost
KubeDNS is running at https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClusterIP is not accessible from outside the cluster. You will have to exec into another pod and use curl to access it.

Comment: Thanks , not really useful for my use-case where i wanted to spin up test containers to invoke from a test application in teh IDE. NodePort is still an option but .... . Windows sucks, as usual. I don;t know why companies insist on providing their IT staff  with Windows "workstations" , IT policies not withstanding:)

Answer (score 0):

CLusterIP cannot be accessible from outside the cluster.
Other method beside execing into pod (as mentioned by Arghya) would be using `kubectl port-forward` command.

Just run:

```
kubectl port-forward pods/<pod-name> <local-port>:<pod-port>
```

and then you can access the pod under `localhost:<local-port>`

Refer to kubernetes documentation for more information about [port forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod).